# Loop through PHP array with preference on which to loop through first

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, foreach

I have a simple array `$arr` with keys that start with `ab-` or `xy-` in different orders. I want to loop through the keys with `ab-` first and they `xy-`.

```
$arr = [
    'ab-283' => 'Hi', // 1 (loop through this first)
    'xy-153' => 'Ok', // 5
    'ab-232' => 'Hello', // 2 (loop this through second...)
    'ab-164' => 'Cool', // 3
    'xy-164' => 'Hmm', // 6
    'ab-164' => 'Yo', // 4
    'xy-164' => 'Yup' // 7
];

foreach ($arr as key => $value) {
}
```

This is what would be the output:

```
Hi
Hello
Cool
Yo
Ok
Hmm
Yup
```

So is there anyway to loop through the `ab-` first and then the `xy-`? Thank you

Comment: Sort it first? foreach is just going to go in order.

Comment: ksort($arr); before the foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it to be completely sorted by key (I assume you don't since it isn't like that in the output you showed), I think you'll just have to go through it twice.

```
foreach (['ab', 'xy'] as $prefix) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 2) == $prefix) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this approach be faster than `ksort()`?

Comment: Well, ksort wouldn't give the output you want. It would sort by the numeric part as well rather than just ab and then xy with the elements of each prefix left in the original order. So it would be like Hello, Hi instead of Hi, Hello, for example.

Comment: If that really doesn't matter, then I would just go with ksort.

Comment: I did a performance test and I put both of them in a `for ($x = 0; $x <= 100000; $x++) {`and `ksort()` was faster. But I am accepting your answer because I had your kind of code in mind but just couldn't think of it! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept whichever one works best for you, though. If sorting by the numeric part doesn't matter, I'd prefer the simplicity of ksort whether it was faster or not, unless the difference was significant. Also, when testing performance like that, keep in mind that the different methods you're comparing _may_ work better/worse depending on the size of the input and other factors like how sorted it already is.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort $arr array by key first.

```
ksort($arr);
```

then foreach.
Your array has the same keys multiple times (xy-164) so the output won't be the same as you posted, but rather:

```
array(5) {
  ["ab-164"]=>
  string(2) "Yo"
  ["ab-232"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  ["ab-283"]=>
  string(2) "Hi"
  ["xy-153"]=>
  string(2) "Ok"
  ["xy-164"]=>
  string(3) "Yup"
}
```